# Convert a path to a polygon?

Tags: javascript, path, fabricjs, polygon

I have a path object, that I've loaded into the canvas via `fabric.loadSVGFromURL`. It imports into fabric.js just fine. I'd like to know the correct way (if there is even a way), to convert this path to a polygon with a points array.

So, in short, is there a way to convert a `Path` object to a `Polygon` object to then make use of the `Polygon`'s points array?

Ultimately, I want to draw a circle at each point of the `Polygon` (which I'm presently doing, but don't know how to do that with a `Path` object).

Just looking for a nudge in the right direction in the Fabric.js docs for doing something like that.

**UPDATES**

1. thought I could use `getCoords()` on my path object, but that only returns the 4 bounding box points. the quest continues.

Comment: Still looking for a way to do this. Most specifically would like to be able to translate the `Path` instructions of relative/absolute coords to a `Polygon`'s absolute coord points.

Comment: A workaround I am using (which is terribly slow and inefficient) is to convert canvas to json, find the path I just added and append "z" as its last element to its path array. Then I use `loadFromJson` method of canvas to load the modified json and then rerender everything. The "z" forces path to close, that is it draws a line from its last point to first point. It is not a solution to your problem because it stays as a path element, but at least in most cases it *looks* like a polygon.